# Why my database tables don't show up when I check using SQLite3?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have some problem with SQLite in Android Studio.

I have created a database, but I can't get the table I created.
Here's the problem

[image]

And here's my `SQLiteOpenHelper` class

```
public class GreenSQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "greencampus.db";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 2;

    //table USER
    public static final String USER_TABLE = "USER";
    public static final String COLUMN_USERNAME = "USERNAME";
    public static final String COLUMN_PASSWORD = "PASWORD";
    public static final String COLUMN_NOREK=  "NOREK";
    public static final String COLUMN_EMAIL = "EMAIL";
    public static final String CREATE_USER =
            "CREATE TABLE" + USER_TABLE + "("
                    + COLUMN_NOREK + "TEXT PRIMARY KEY,"
            +COLUMN_USERNAME + "TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_PASSWORD + "TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_EMAIL + "TEXT)";

    //table tapcash
    public static final String TAPCASH_TABLE = "TAPCASH";
    public static final String COLUMN_FNAME = "FNAME";
    public static final String COLUMN_LNAME = "LNAME";
    public static final String COLUMN_SALDOT = "SALDOT";
    public static final String COLUMN_SALDOR = "SALDOR";
    public static final String FOREIGN_KEY_NOREK = "USER_NOREK";
    public static final String CREATE_TAPCASH =
        "CREATE TABLE" + TAPCASH_TABLE +"("
                + BaseColumns._ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                COLUMN_SALDOT + "TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_SALDOR + "TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_FNAME + "TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_LNAME + "TEXT, " +
                FOREIGN_KEY_NOREK + "TEXT, " +
                "FOREIGN KEY(" + FOREIGN_KEY_NOREK + ") REFERENCES USER(NOREK)";


    //table bus
    public static final String BUS_TABLE = "BUS";
    public static final String COLUMN_NOBUS = "NOBUS";
    public static final String COLUMN_JADWAL = "JADWAL";
    public static final String FOREIGN_KEY_SHELTER ="SHELTER_ID";
    public static final String CREATE_BUS =
    "CREATE TABLE" + BUS_TABLE + "("
            + BaseColumns._ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            COLUMN_NOBUS + "TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_JADWAL + "TEXT, " +
            FOREIGN_KEY_SHELTER + "INTEGER, " +
            "FOREIGN KEY(" + FOREIGN_KEY_SHELTER + ") REFERENCES SHELTER(_ID)";

    //table shelter
    public static final String SHELTER_TABLE = "SHELTER";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAMAS = "NAMA";
    public static final String COLUMN_KOORDINATS = "KOORDINAT";
    public static final String CREATE_SHELTER =
        "CREATE TABLE" + SHELTER_TABLE + "("
                + BaseColumns._ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
        COLUMN_NAMAS + "TEXT, " +
        COLUMN_KOORDINATS + "TEXT) ";

    //table map
    public static final String MAP_TABLE = "MAP";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAMAM = "NAMA MAP";
    public static final String COLUMN_KOORDINATM = "KOORDINAT";
    public static final String CREATE_MAP =
        "CREATE TABLE" + MAP_TABLE + "("
                + BaseColumns._ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
        COLUMN_NAMAM + "TEXT, " +
        COLUMN_KOORDINATM + "TEXT) ";

    public GreenSQLiteHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION );
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try{
            db.execSQL(CREATE_USER);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TAPCASH);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_BUS);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_SHELTER);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_MAP);
        }
        catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
       try {
           db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + USER_TABLE);
           db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + TAPCASH_TABLE);
           db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + BUS_TABLE);
           db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + SHELTER_TABLE);
           db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + MAP_TABLE);
           onCreate(db);
       }
       catch (SQLException e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
}
```

I'm using a datasource class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class GreenDataSource {
    private Context mContext;
    GreenSQLiteHelper mGreenSQLiteHelper;

    public GreenDataSource(Context context){
        mContext = context;
        mGreenSQLiteHelper = new GreenSQLiteHelper(context);
        SQLiteDatabase database = mGreenSQLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        database.close();
    }
}
```

This is my Activity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register_activity);
        GreenDataSource myDb =  new GreenDataSource(this);
    }
}
```

and they said that onCreate in SQLiteOpenHelper only run one time. so what should i do?

please help me, I'm on my deadline

Comment: Did you make it work?

Answer (score 0):

**All** your table creation commands are missing the necessary spaces between the names and the datatypes and/or statements.

They need to be rewritten like so:

```
public static final String CREATE_USER =
        "CREATE TABLE " + USER_TABLE + "("
                + COLUMN_NOREK + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY,"
        +COLUMN_USERNAME + " TEXT,"
        + COLUMN_PASSWORD + " TEXT,"
        + COLUMN_EMAIL + " TEXT)";

//table tapcash
public static final String TAPCASH_TABLE = "TAPCASH";
public static final String COLUMN_FNAME = "FNAME";
public static final String COLUMN_LNAME = "LNAME";
public static final String COLUMN_SALDOT = "SALDOT";
public static final String COLUMN_SALDOR = "SALDOR";
public static final String FOREIGN_KEY_NOREK = "USER_NOREK";
public static final String CREATE_TAPCASH =
    "CREATE TABLE " + TAPCASH_TABLE +"("
            + BaseColumns._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            COLUMN_SALDOT + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_SALDOR + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_FNAME + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_LNAME + " TEXT, " +
            FOREIGN_KEY_NOREK + " TEXT, " +
            "FOREIGN KEY(" + FOREIGN_KEY_NOREK + ") REFERENCES USER(NOREK))";


//table bus
public static final String BUS_TABLE = "BUS";
public static final String COLUMN_NOBUS = "NOBUS";
public static final String COLUMN_JADWAL = "JADWAL";
public static final String FOREIGN_KEY_SHELTER ="SHELTER_ID";
public static final String CREATE_BUS =
"CREATE TABLE " + BUS_TABLE + "("
        + BaseColumns._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
        COLUMN_NOBUS + " TEXT, " +
        COLUMN_JADWAL + " TEXT, " +
        FOREIGN_KEY_SHELTER + " INTEGER, " +
        "FOREIGN KEY(" + FOREIGN_KEY_SHELTER + ") REFERENCES SHELTER(_ID))";

//table shelter
public static final String SHELTER_TABLE = "SHELTER";
public static final String COLUMN_NAMAS = "NAMA";
public static final String COLUMN_KOORDINATS = "KOORDINAT";
public static final String CREATE_SHELTER =
    "CREATE TABLE " + SHELTER_TABLE + "("
            + BaseColumns._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
    COLUMN_NAMAS + " TEXT, " +
    COLUMN_KOORDINATS + " TEXT) ";

//table map
public static final String MAP_TABLE = "MAP";
public static final String COLUMN_NAMAM = "NAMA MAP";
public static final String COLUMN_KOORDINATM = "KOORDINAT";
public static final String CREATE_MAP =
    "CREATE TABLE " + MAP_TABLE + "("
            + BaseColumns._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
    COLUMN_NAMAM + " TEXT, " +
    COLUMN_KOORDINATM + " TEXT) ";
```

Comment: yeah that right, thanks. what should i do next? they said onCreate in SQLiteOpenHelper only run one time? so what i have to do?

Comment: Uninstall and reinstall your app

Comment: i already did that but after i check with adb again, there is no databases folder. what should i do then? so confuse right now

Comment: **Where** are you looking for the databases folder?

Comment: adb shell -> cd data/data/com.example.username.myproject/

Comment: You are missing a `/`. It's `/data/data/com.example.username.myproject/`

Comment: im not sure that's the problem cause i already in myproject directory.  only cache dir and code_cache that appear

Comment: Which is the Android OS you're using? Anyway, you can get the database path by using `getDatabasePath()`

Comment: ok it's work, what u have to do is uninstall your app, change the database name then reinstall

Answer (score 0):

Your create table strings are wrong, they missing some spaces. For example at the user table creation:

```
public static final String CREATE_USER =
        "CREATE TABLE" + USER_TABLE + "("
                + COLUMN_NOREK + "TEXT PRIMARY KEY,"
        +COLUMN_USERNAME + "TEXT,"
        + COLUMN_PASSWORD + "TEXT,"
        + COLUMN_EMAIL + "TEXT)";
```

The code above will concat the following string:

```
public static final String CREATE_USER = "CREATE TABLEUSER(NOREKTEXT PRIMARY KEY,USERNAMETEXT,PASSWORDTEXT,EMAILTEXT)";
```

The correct solution will be this:

```
public static final String CREATE_USER =
        "CREATE TABLE " + USER_TABLE + " ("
                + COLUMN_NOREK + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY,"
        +COLUMN_USERNAME + " TEXT,"
        + COLUMN_PASSWORD + " TEXT,"
        + COLUMN_EMAIL + " TEXT)";
```

I hope you see the difference with the spaces included. Check your SQL script strings again, fix them and try run the code again.

Comment: yeah that right, thanks. what should i do next? they said onCreate in SQLiteOpenHelper only run one time? so what i have to do?

Comment: You have two options:
1.) delete your app and install it again
2.) Increase the version number of your database, then reinstall the app. The onUpgrade method will be called and it'll create the tables with the corrected script.

Comment: i already did that but after i check with adb again, there is no databases folder. what should i do then? so confuse right now

Comment: I just found that there is another syntax issue in your code. When you make a table with foreign keys, you didnt close the create table command with a bracket. So put a ')' to the end of the CREATE_TAPCASH and CREATE_BUS strings.

Comment: ok it's work, what u have to do is uninstall your app, change the database name then reinstall